# Replacing the World in Cuis/Squeak Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How does one replace the PasteUpMorph that is the 'world' in Cuis/Squeak Smalltalk with a new instance of PasteupMorph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Squeak, you open a new project. Each project has an associated world.